# Подсчет кол-ва строк MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

У меня есть запрос, который выводит много строк, я знаю их количество (в БД выходит подсказка - `109898`)

`select sum(kol) from planzp where kzajnpp not in ('СН') and kol not in (0) group by kprt`

Как мне написать запрос, чтобы вывелось именно количество этих строк? Пробовал запросом ниже, но выходит число больше чем должно быть, что не так? (получается `146854`, что явно больше чем должно быть)

````
select count(*) from planzp
where kol IN
(select sum(kol) from planzp where kzajnpp not in ('СН') and kol not in (0) group by kprt) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Количество записей в итоговом наборе равно количеству уникальных значений выражения группировки. Т.е. требуется простое

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT kprt) 
from planzp 
where kzajnpp not in ('СН') and kol not in (0)
```

PS. `.. where kol IN (select sum(kol) ..` - крайне странная конструкция. Сравнивать отдельное значение с **суммой** значений...

Comment: Действительно, я не подумал об использовании дистинкта, спасибо!!!